# Exclude user in match MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to add Not in query. but unfortunately I'm not getting the required result. i want to get result where user is not equal to userid. But I'm confused as to how I can add that. I tried multiple scenarios but failed.

```
server.get('/myFeedback', (req, res) => {
            var userid = req.query.userID;
            //console.log(req.query);
        db.collection("tweetsWithSentimentFeedback").aggregate( [
                              {
                                $group: {
                                   _id: {
                                        topic: "$topic",
                                        group : "$group",
                                        type : "$type", 
                                        user    :   "$userName"
                                   },
                                   count: { $sum: 1 }    
                                  }
                              },{    $group: {
                                    _id: {
                                        topic: "$_id.topic",
                                        group : "$_id.group",

                                        },
                                    typeAndCount: {
                                        $addToSet: {
                                            type: "$_id.type",
                                            count: "$count"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    userName: {
                                        $addToSet: {
                                            user: "$_id.userName"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    totalCount: {
                                        $sum: "$count"
                                    }
                                }
                      },
                      { $match: { $and: [ { totalCount: { $gt: 0, $lt: 15 } }, {userEqual: { $ne: [ "$userName.user", userid ] }} ] } },
                            // Then sort
                               { "$sort": { "totalCount": -1 } }
                           ], (err, result) => {
                               if (err) {
                                   console.log(err);
                               }
                               res.status(200).send(result);
                           } );
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a `$match` as a first stage to filter the `user`.

```
{ $match: { userName: { $ne: userid } } }
```

Update:

```
db.collection("tweetsWithSentimentFeedback").aggregate(
    [{
        $group: {
            _id: {
                topic: "$topic",
                group: "$group",
                type: "$type",
                user: "$userName"
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                topic: "$_id.topic",
                group: "$_id.group"
            },
            typeAndCount: {
                $addToSet: {
                    type: "$_id.type",
                    count: "$count"
                }
            },
            userName: {
                $addToSet: "$_id.userName"
            },
            totalCount: {
                $sum: "$count"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $match: {
            {
                totalCount: {
                    $gt: 0,
                    $lt: 15
                }
            },
            {
                userName: {
                    $ne: userid
                }
            }
        }
    }, , {
        $sort: {
            totalCount: -1
        }
    }])
```

Comment: what if i dont want to add  userName: {
                                        $addToSet: {
                                            user: "$_id.userName"
                                        }
                                    }, thn can i still exclude userid? because i don't want this field. and I'm new in mongodb. I dont get your point 1st stage.

Comment: yeah just add the match stage to the pipeline and remove the above code.

Comment: alright updated answer to include complete aggregation part

Comment: there is a problem with this ne. it exclude users and then on remaining data it apply grouping. for example if a record has 10 entries. then it exclude all user from that and then it apply grouping. i want to exclude all those groups which contain that user. if a certain group contain that user then it should exclude that group.first it should make groups of record then it check if a group has that entrie then exclude it.